# mysql DELETE multiple tables

Tags: mysql, cascade

is it possible to delete from multiple tables?

i have 3 tables all related by an id, so where the id is the same delete the relevant information.

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify ON DELETE CASCADE rule for your tables. Have a look at [MySQL docs on foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Cascading rules are exactly what you need to force data integrity.

With those rules properly specified when you delete the parent row all children rows will be automatically deleted by RDBMS.

Comment: my tables are currently myisam, will it affect anything if i edit to swap them to innoDB?

Comment: It depends on your tables, generally - no, it won't affect the data. They do have a slightly different set of features though. The biggest downside of InnoDB is probably a lack of full-text search.

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB you can have a foreign key by setting it up as foreign keys to cascade.  Please see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html